# [Kaa]: Is Kaa implementation OneM2M compliant?

Tags: kaa, onem2m

I found Kaa very relevant for our application but we need a platform which is oneM2M compliant. Is Kaa implementation OneM2M compliant?

Answer (score 1):

Current Kaa implementation is not oneM2M compliant. You will need an additional services for integration and data sharing if that is what you need.

The future Kaa releases are planned to be much more flexible and might add complience to oneM2M in the future.